# Json.NET serialize collection partially

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

How to serialize a **collection** partially depending on some conditions of contained objects?
I already looked at `JsonConverter` and `ContractResolver`, but still cant figure it out.

I'm talking about the general case.

For example: `IList`, int numbers => only even numbers 
I just want some of items to be ignored during serialization.

Comment: What does your collection contain? what is your input? what output do you expect? What are those conditions and how do they effect the output?

Comment: Does it really matter? I'm talking about the general case.
For example: IList, int numbers, only even numbers
I just want some of items to be ignored during serialization.

Comment: Number of answers shows it really matters.

Comment: And that is really sad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a sample in which I only serialize even numbers.

```
Container contrainer = new Container();
contrainer.Full = Enumerable.Range(1, 20).ToArray();

JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
String str = serializer.Serialize(contrainer);

public class Container
{
    // don't serialize
    [ScriptIgnore]
    public Int32[] Full { get; set; }

    public Int32[] Partial
    {
        //select what you want to serialize
        get { return this.Full.Where(i => (i % 2) == 0).ToArray(); }
        set { this.Full = value; }
    }
}
```

**Result**

```
{"Partial":[2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20]}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Heh, I already thought about that kind of trick. But that's not a fair move, it's adding a new collection not telling serializer how to handle the old one.